# ArrayList.contains incorrectly consider value as part of array :D

Tags: java, arraylist, jstl

I have this array with some IDs, named `arrayListIDs`:

`[2176, 117]`

I loop and check each one if its ID is in the array or not.

So somewhere in the loop I have:

```
<c:if test="${arrayListIDs.contains((Integer) product.productID)}">
...
</c:if>
```

For the value `11` it returns `true` I would like to know how this is possible?

I have `117` and not `11` ...

Or am I missing something?

Comment: Why are you sure that array doesn't contain 11 or that the value you are testing is actually 11?

Comment: Cause I have printed both ... take a look at this: https://www.screencast.com/t/0Jso7Fl1pxW ... I've printed the array with the IDs on the top and product ID at the bottom. (AAA and BBB is just dummy text.)

Comment: Can you please post more code, kind of what is the approximate body of if statement, and where does product comes from

Comment: From database. It's array of items, I'm looping through them and inside the loop I'm checking it's ID if it's part of the `ListArray`.

Comment: I understood that, sorry i didn't say clear, i meant from kind of: from request, from another array etc. And why are you sure that it returns true for 11?

Comment: At the beginning of the JSP file I'm getting the items from the DB and have them in a `collection`. (The code for that is legacy.) Then I'm iterating the collection and put only the IDs in this `ListArray`. (The code for that is mine.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135377/discussion-between-dmytro-grynets-and-pesho-hristov).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that `ArrayList.contains` is part of `JSF` and not `JSP` or `JSTL`. And your environment doesn't support `JSF`.

I had the same problem and solved it this way:

1. Define a string, where I'll put the IDs: `String productsIDs = "|";`.
2. Loop through your data and put the IDs in this string:

   ```
   while(xxx.hasNext()) {
       [SomeType] product = (SomeType) itr.next();
       productsIDs += product.getProductID();
       productsIDs += "|";
   }
   ```

This way, at the end I have string with the IDs like `|1|2|33|400|`.

3. And after that you check like this:

   ```
   <c:if test="${fn:contains(productsIDs, currentProductID)}">
   ```

`fn:contains` works only with strings, so this way you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're so convinced that in your list there is no element `11` why don't you output the array in the JSTL and see what you're getting at that stage?

Better yet, try running through the array in a different way instead of using `contains()`

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${arrayListIDs}">
  <c:if test="${item eq 11}">
    <h1> Found 11 </h1>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

See what output you get here.

Comment: I've printed the array and the ID for each element: https://www.screencast.com/t/0Jso7Fl1pxW ... the array is on the top and the product ID is at the bottom. (AAA and BBB is dummy text.)

Comment: That worked ... but this way I have nested loops. And this is something I wanted to avoid.

Comment: O, i've finally got it, arrayListIDs is string, isn't it?

Comment: It is array list ... not a string ... declared like `ArrayList<Integer> arrayListIDs = new ArrayList<Integer>();`  and then with several `arrayListIDs.add(...)` I'm adding the values.